# Expressão regular "permissiva" para detectar extensões e hosts permitidos

Tags: javascript, python, regex

eu tenho uma lista com algums links

```
https://www.exemplo.com/
https://www.exemplo.com/home/
https://www.exemplo.com/logo.png
https://intranet.exemplo.com/
https://admin.exemplo.com/login
https://www.exemplo.com/sobre/
https://www.exemplo.com/shell.php.log
https://www.exemplo.com/background.jpg
```

e estou querendo identificar os links que comecem com

```
https://www.exemplo.com/
```

e que não terminem com **jpg** ou **png**

no caso as seguines urls estariam bloqueadas

```
    https://www.exemplo.com/logo.png
    https://www.exemplo.com/background.jpg
    https://intranet.exemplo.com/
    https://admin.exemplo.com/login
```

Comment: Em python? Ou em javascript?

Comment: em javascript mas tambem pode ser em python @Miguel

Comment: vou fazer com os dois

Comment: Vale mencionar que isso é coisa pra comparação de strings, não precisa de RegEx pra coisa simples desse jeito.

Comment: É preciso ser com regex? O @Bacco tem razão, neste caso não é necessário. Podemos fazer mais simplemente

Comment: @Miguel se quiser, poste com RegEx pra atender a pergunta, mas dê um exemplo com substring também, acho que aí valoriza a resposta.

Comment: @Bacco se eu soubesse eu nao estaria aqui perguntando eu estou tentando no regexonline mas nao esta querendo percorrer toda a lista

Comment: @NikoBellic tem varios testes online. Quase todos vc tem que indicar que é multiline em algum lugar pra testar listas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temos então:

```
urls = ["https://www.exemplo.com/", "https://www.exemplo.com/home/", "https://www.exemplo.com/logo.png", "https://intranet.exemplo.com/", "https://admin.exemplo.com/login", "https://www.exemplo.com/sobre/", "https://www.exemplo.com/shell.php.log", "https://www.exemplo.com/background.jpg"]
```

Vamos filtrar aqueles que acabam com png/jpg ou que não têm o "www".

Com e regex em python:

```
import re

bloqueados = []
for url in urls:
    img = re.compile('^.*\.(jpg|JPG|png)$')
    www = re.compile('(.*?)//www.(.*?)')
    if(img.match(url) or not www.match(url)):
        bloqueados.append(url)
print(bloqueados) # ['https://www.exemplo.com/logo.png', 'https://intranet.exemplo.com/', 'https://admin.exemplo.com/login', 'https://www.exemplo.com/background.jpg']
```

OU

```
import re
bloqueados = [url for url in urls if(re.compile('^.*\.(jpg|JPG|png)$').match(url) or re.compile('(.*?)//www.(.*?)').match(url) == None)]
print(bloqueados) # ['https://www.exemplo.com/logo.png', 'https://intranet.exemplo.com/', 'https://admin.exemplo.com/login', 'https://www.exemplo.com/background.jpg']
```

Se bem que para este caso simples eu não usaria regex, faria:

```
bloqueados = [url for url in urls if url[-4:] == '.png' or url[-4:] == '.jpg' or 'https://www.' not in url]
print(bloqueados) # ['https://www.exemplo.com/logo.png', 'https://intranet.exemplo.com/', 'https://admin.exemplo.com/login', 'https://www.exemplo.com/background.jpg']
```

Com regex em javascript:

```
var bloqueados = []
var ext;
var www;
for(var url in urls) {
    if(/^.*\.(jpg|png)$/.test(urls[url]) || !/(.*?)\/\/www.(.*?)/.test(urls[url])) {
        bloqueados.push(urls[url])
    }
}
console.log(bloqueados); // ["https://www.exemplo.com/logo.png", "https://intranet.exemplo.com/", "https://admin.exemplo.com/login", "https://www.exemplo.com/background.jpg"]
```

Sem regex em javascript:

```
var bloqueados = []
var ext;
var www;
for(var url in urls) {
    exts = urls[url].split('.');
    ext = exts[exts.length - 1];
    if(ext == 'png' || ext == 'jpg' || urls[url].indexOf("//www.") < 0) {
        bloqueados.push(urls[url])
    }
}
console.log(bloqueados); // ["https://www.exemplo.com/logo.png", "https://intranet.exemplo.com/", "https://admin.exemplo.com/login", "https://www.exemplo.com/background.jpg"]
```

Comment: muito bem bolada a ultima expressao @Miguel vlw mesmo

Comment: Ainda estou a trabalhar na solução com javascript se quiser

Comment: nao nao, nao quero desgastar as suas habilidades eu perguntei nos dois por que a sintaxe e parecida mas a sua resposta ja resolveu por aqui valeu

Comment: Já tinha começado :P, não faz mal. Já tem solução em cima para javascript também @NikoBellic. Obgado Niko

Comment: @NikoBellic ainda arranjei uma melhor solução, na ultima solução de python. Acho que vai gostar mais

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma simples de conseguir o mesmo resultado seria usando a propriedade [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) nativa do JavaScript, exemplo:

```
function filtrarUrls(lista) {
    var base = 'https://www.exemplo.com';

    lista = lista
              .filter((url) => { return url.indexOf(base) > -1 })
              .filter((url) => { return url.match(/(.jpg|.png)/g) === null });

    return lista;
}
```

E para utilizar a função:

```
var urls = ['https://url1.com', 'https://url2.com', ...];

var urlsFiltradas = filtrarUrls(urls); //retorna um array apenas com as URLs filtradas.
```